# Using multiple vhost templates in puppet

Tags: puppet, puppetlabs-apache

I'd like to use multiple vhost templates from my apache module in my nodes manifest, and so far not having any luck.

I have one vhost template in my apache module that looks like this. This is my apache::vhost template:

```
cat modules/apache/templates/vhost.conf.erb
<VirtualHost *:<%= port %>>
   ServerName <%= name %>
<%if serveraliases.is_a? Array -%>
<% serveraliases.each do |name| -%>
<%= " ServerAlias #{name}\n" %><% end -%>
<% elsif serveraliases != '' -%>
<%= "   ServerAlias #{serveraliases}" -%>
<% end -%>

   php_value newrelic.appname <%= name  %>

    KeepAlive   On
    KeepAliveTimeout 5
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
    LogFormat "{ \
      \"host\":\"<%= name %>.<%= domain %>\", \
      \"path\":\"/var/log/httpd/jf_<%= name %>_access_log\", \
      \"tags\":[\"Jokefire <%= name %>\"], \
      \"message\": \"%h %l %u %t \\\"%r\\\" %>s %b\", \
      \"timestamp\": \"%{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z}t\", \
      \"clientip\": \"%a\", \
      \"duration\": %D, \
      \"status\": %>s, \
      \"request\": \"%U%q\", \
      \"urlpath\": \"%U\", \
      \"urlquery\": \"%q\", \
      \"method\": \"%m\", \
      \"bytes\": %B, \
      \"vhost\": \"%v\" \
    }" <%= name %>_access_json
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/jf_<%= name %>_access_log <%= name %>_access_json
    LogLevel  debug
    ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/jf_<%= name %>_error_log
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    DocumentRoot <%= docroot %>
    <Directory <%= docroot %>>
      Options  Indexes  FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
    </Directory>
     ServerSignature  On
</VirtualHost>
```

And when I define that template in my nodes.pp manifest it worked totally fine:

```
   apache::vhost { 'dev.example.com':
      port => 80,
      docroot => '/var/www/jf-wp',
      ssl => false,
      priority => 002,
      }
```

But when I try to use another vhost template with different settings in my nodes.pp manifest I get an error. This is the apache::vhost_admin template that I can't get to work in my nodes.pp manifest:

```
 #cat modules/apache/templates/vhost_admin.conf.erb
<VirtualHost *:<%= port %>>
   ServerName <%= name %>
<%if serveraliases.is_a? Array -%>
<% serveraliases.each do |name| -%>
<%= " ServerAlias #{name}\n" %><% end -%>
<% elsif serveraliases != '' -%>
<%= "   ServerAlias #{serveraliases}" -%>
<% end -%>

   php_value newrelic.enabled false

    KeepAlive   On
    KeepAliveTimeout 5
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
    LogFormat "{ \
      \"host\":\"<%= name %>.<%= domain %>\", \
      \"path\":\"/var/log/httpd/jf_<%= name %>_access_log\", \
      \"tags\":[\"Jokefire <%= name %>\"], \
      \"message\": \"%h %l %u %t \\\"%r\\\" %>s %b\", \
      \"timestamp\": \"%{%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z}t\", \
      \"clientip\": \"%a\", \
      \"duration\": %D, \
      \"status\": %>s, \
      \"request\": \"%U%q\", \
      \"urlpath\": \"%U\", \
      \"urlquery\": \"%q\", \
      \"method\": \"%m\", \
      \"bytes\": %B, \
      \"vhost\": \"%v\" \
    }" <%= name %>_access_json
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/jf_<%= name %>_access_log <%= name %>_access_json
    LogLevel  debug
    ErrorLog  /var/log/httpd/jf_<%= name %>_error_log
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
    DocumentRoot <%= docroot %>
    <Directory <%= docroot %>>
      Options  Indexes  FollowSymLinks
      AllowOverride All
      Order allow,deny
      allow from all
    </Directory>
     ServerSignature  On
</VirtualHost>
```

And when I try to define apache::vhost_admin in my nodes.pp file:

```
apache::vhost_admin { 'admin.example.com':
  port => 80,
  docroot => '/var/www/admin',
  ssl => false,
  priority => 004,
  serveraliases => 'www.admin.example.com',
  }
```

When I define the apache::vhost_admin template in the nodes.pp manifest is when I get the following error:

```
 Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 400 on SERVER: Puppet::Parser::AST::Resource failed with e
rror ArgumentError: Invalid resource type apache::vhost_admin at /etc/puppet/environments/production/manifests/nodes.p
p:139 on node web1.jokefire.com
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
enter code here
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I define multiple vhost definitions in puppet, each with different settings?

Comment: Are you using apache::vhost or apache::vhost_admin? It's totally unclear for me what you are trying to do. Can you post your apache::vhost_?? here?

Comment: Hi christi, I'm trying to use both apache::vhost, and apache::vhost_admin. And when I try to use apache::vhost_admin, I'm getting an error. But I don't get an error when using apache::vhost.  What I'd like to be able to do is use both templates but I'm unsure of how to achieve that.

Sorry if I wasn't clear. I've edited the post to try and make it a little more clear what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Is apache::vhost_admin a define or a class?

Comment: it's a define. Both apache::vhost and apache::vhost_admin are denitions.

Comment: Is the vhost_admin.pp file in the same path as vhost.pp? It looks like puppet can't find the define.

Comment: Also, check the name of the define inside vhost_admin.pp file

Comment: Hi cristi, these are template files so they have .erb endings. And yes they're both in the same exact directory:

#ls -l environments/production/modules/apache/templates/vhost.conf.erb environments/production/modules/apache/templates/vhost_admin.conf.erb
-rw-r--r--  1 TimothyDunphy  staff  1352 Aug 16 20:37 environments/production/modules/apache/templates/vhost.conf.erb
-rw-r--r--  1 TimothyDunphy  staff  1345 Nov  8 13:31 environments/production/modules/apache/templates/vhost_admin.conf.erb

And that's what I was unsure of. It seems there's no 'name' attribute inside the template definition.

Comment: So what I'm wondering is, how does puppet determine the name to use for the definition? I assumed that it would be based on the name of the file without an extension. Because apache::vhost works I assumed that apache::vhost_admin or any other variant would work. 

But it seems my assumption was incorrect, because when I try to use any other template definition, puppet throws the error I just showed you.

Comment: These are all the templates I have defined:
#ls -l environments/production/modules/apache/templates/
total 184
-rw-r--r--  1 TimothyDunphy  staff  12029 Nov  1 10:00 httpd-2.4.conf.erb
-rw-r--r--  1 TimothyDunphy  staff  11966 Oct 17 23:55 httpd.conf.erb
-rw-r--r--  1 TimothyDunphy  staff  34274 Aug 16 20:37 httpd.conf.erb.bak

Comment: -rw-r--r--  1 TimothyDunphy  staff   1352 Aug 16 20:37 vhost.conf.erb
-rw-r--r--  1 TimothyDunphy  staff   1350 Aug 16 20:37 vhost.conf.erb.bak
-rw-r--r--  1 TimothyDunphy  staff   1345 Nov  8 13:31 vhost_admin.conf.erb
-rw-r--r--  1 TimothyDunphy  staff   1388 Aug 16 20:37 vhost_auth.conf.erb
-rw-r--r--  1 TimothyDunphy  staff  11428 Aug 16 20:37 vhost_foswiki.conf.erb
-rw-r--r--  1 TimothyDunphy  staff   2678 Aug 16 20:37 vhost_trac.conf.erb

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. You don't call templates. You calll classes or defines in your puppet code. Inside your manifests directory from your module you should find a vhost.pp file. This file is doing all the work: defines parameters, default values, calls a file resource which receives the template as the content. Most probably you don't have a vhost_admin.pp file that you will need if you want to call apache::vhost_admin inside your puppet code.

Comment: Thanks! Got it now. It works. Appreciate your advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the discussion with @bluethundr, it looks like the "apache::vhost_admin" define was missing.